# Accessing app's class from the Device Activity Monitor Extension target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have created a Device Activity Monitor Extension target in my SwiftUI app. I have a model that I wanna access from the new target. Can you please help me to access MyModel from MyMonitor? This is the first time I'm using a different target. [image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem, has yours been resolved?

Comment: @AhmedYusuf yes, just select the swift file and open the right panel, then check the target under the Target Membership

Comment: Hi, thank you, you saved my day. I can call local notification from MyModel, but somehow when I check MyModel. shared.familyActivitySelection and showing the count using local notification, the value remain empty even though I already set it from my AppDelegate